# "One of which" or "one of them"

Tags: word-choice

What sounds better? Or which one is correct?

> There are two people one of **which** is left-handed.
>
> There are two people one of **them** is left-handed.

Comment: The second one is ungrammatical because it's two separate clauses ("there are two people" and "one of them is left-handed") run together with no conjunction or semicolon.  "There are two people **and** one of them is left-handed" would be grammatical, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must choose between "which" of "them" then

> There are two people one of **them** is left-handed.

would be better, but

> There are two people one of **whom** is left-handed.

would be best.

Comment: Just remember to punctuate your choice correctly: There are two people; one of them is left-handed (semi-colon), or There are two people, one of whom is left-handed (comma).

Answer (score -2):

" 
we can say

There are two people.One of  them is left-handed, but I don't know who he is.

or 
There are two persons. The one ,which is left-handed , is a teacher.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Answers on ELL should be written to the best of your ability with special attention paid to spelling, punctuation, and using complete sentences. You have numerous errors in your answer. Please [edit] it to correct them.